# Can't insert event in a Google Calendar with service Account

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I found a lot of post with the same issue but none of these post has an' efficient answer ... so I try by myself.

I need to manage some meeting room's Google calendar from my nodejs backend

I followed this link https://medium.com/iceapple-tech-talks/integration-with-google-calendar-api-using-service-account-1471e6e102c8 which is the most recent tuto I found.

1/ I enable Google Calendar API
2/ I have created a service account with role “Service Account Token Creator”
3/ I have downloaded credentials

When I try to insert a new event in a calendar with this code :

```js
const client = new JWT({
    email: credentials.client_email,
    key: credentials.private_key,
    scopes: [
      // set the right scope
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
    ],
  });

  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3" });

  try {
    const res = await calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: calendarId,
      auth: client,
      requestBody: gEvent,
    });
    return res.data.htmlLink;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Could not create event: ${error.message}`);
  }
```

I catch a 404 Error [image]

I usemeeting room's email address as calendarId

I tried to share the calendar to service account user but I can't select 'Make changes to events"
[image: share room calendat from admin account]

I tried to add Domain-wide delegation to my service account with scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" but it does not work any more ...

any help is welcome because I don't have any other idea ...